# Suppose $\lim y_n = y$, is this a valid proof of $\lim \frac{1}{y_n} = \frac{1}{y}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I understand that this isn't the standard proof provided in most introductory Real Analysis texts, but would like to see if this proof is valid.

Suppose that $\lim x_n = x$ and $\lim y_n = y$, and we have previously proved that $\lim x_n y_n = xy$.

By the multiplicative inverse property of real numbers, $\left( y_n \times \frac{1}{y_n} = 1 \right) \Rightarrow \lim \left( y_n \times \frac{1}{y_n} \right) = \lim 1 = 1$

Since  $\lim x_n y_n = xy$, then $\lim \left( y_n \times \frac{1}{y_n} \right) = \lim y_n \times \lim \frac{1}{y_n} = y \times \lim \frac{1}{y_n} = 1 \iff \lim \frac{1}{y_n}  = \frac{1}{y}$

Of course, this proof is only valid for $y \neq 0$ but this assumption holds since we assumed that the sequence $\frac{1}{y_n}$ is defined.

Comment: That's not a valid proof. It would be correct if you were given that $\lim1/y_n$ _exists_.

Comment: Ilustrative bogus proof: suppose $a_n = (-1)^n$ and let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.  Then $L = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} - a_n = -L$ implying $L = 0$.  So $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n = 0$.

Comment: Do you know that limits pass through continuous functions?

Comment: If $y_n$ are bounded away from 0 for large enough n, i.e. $|y_n|\gt c$ for large n, then $\frac{1}{y_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, since $|\frac{1}{y_n}-\frac{1}{y_m}|=|\frac{y_n-y_m}{y_ny_m}|\le |\frac{y_m-y_n}{c^2}|$.Therefore $lim \frac{1}{y_n}$ exist as long as $\lim  y_n$ exists.